# What does 「にすん」 mean in this phrase?

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation

[image: Here is the phrase with the structure highlighted, from the "Blood Plus" manga.]

Above shows the phrase with the structure highlighted, from the "Blood Plus" manga.

Maybe it means "to decide to be", being a contraction of にする, with the translation being "Over here it's hard to handle just deciding to be the enemy of the criminals of the humanity"?

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes る can contract to ん. You may have seen 「何してんの？」 in the past.

Additionally, 「相手にする」is a set phrase meaning 'to deal with'. 'We've got our hands full just dealing with human criminals.'